# How to remove mirroring effect from rotation

Tags: css

Having trouble with rotating over the Y axis. I want the image to not be mirrored. What am I missing?

```css
/*Here is where we flip the image*/
.flip-box {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 325px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  perspective: 1000px;
  padding: 25px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: 425px;
}
/*Needed to position the front and back*/
.flip-box-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
/*Horizontal flip*/
.flip-box:hover .flip-box-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg)
}
/*Position front and back*/
.flip-box-front {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
/*Style the back side*/
.flip-box-back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg)
}
```

```html
<div class="flip-box">
  <div class="flip-box-inner">
    <div class="flip-box-front">
      <img src="assets/frank-herbert.jpeg" alt="A photo of Frank Herbert at 50 years old." style="height: 325px;width: 3000px;">
    </div>
    <div class="flip-box-back">
      <img src="assets/dune-hardcover.jpg" alt="The cover of the Dune Novel." style="height:325px; width:300px;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div
```

With the `.flip-box-back` class, it solves the problem, but goes haywire when its rotating back to the first image.

Comment: I added `display:none;` to `.flip-box-front` --  Is this the desired result? --> https://jsfiddle.net/hq8ufv2d/

Comment: its working alright - just change `width: 3000px` to 300px: https://jsfiddle.net/o1tfzm3y/

Comment: what a typo, thank you for pointing that out. It works, but when its rotating back and forth, theres a frame issue, doesnt look very fluid. This is for the freecodecamp tribute page project, want it to dazzle without the razzle.

Comment: if you run the code snippet here, i see the problem, but not sure what is causing it to be mirrored while not hovering

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `backface-visibility: hidden;` to the back like you did to the front:

```css
/*Here is where we flip the image*/
.flip-box {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 325px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  perspective: 1000px;
  padding: 25px;
  left: 50%;
}
/*Needed to position the front and back*/
.flip-box-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
/*Horizontal flip*/
.flip-box:hover .flip-box-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg)
}
/*Position front and back*/
.flip-box-front {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
/*Style the back side*/
.flip-box-back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="flip-box">
  <div class="flip-box-inner">
    <div class="flip-box-front">
      <img src="assets/frank-herbert.jpeg" alt="A photo of Frank Herbert at 50 years old." style="height: 325px;width: 3000px;">
    </div>
    <div class="flip-box-back">
      <img src="assets/dune-hardcover.jpg" alt="The cover of the Dune Novel." style="height:325px; width:300px;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div
```

Comment: thank you so much. I was trying everything to get it to work. :)

Comment: @Evermind welcome, don't forget to accep the answer if it solves your issue